# inserting numbers of rows with NA value with the condition of minimum row requirement for each entity in R

Tags: r, insert, na

I have a dataframe as below. I would like to set a minimum row variable (let's call it `min_row`) for each `ID`, it means that each `ID` should have at least `min_row` records. if it does not have, I wanna insert a row for that `ID` with `NA` value for the other column (here is `subject` column).

```
min_row_id=3
df
ID    subject
1      A1
1      A2
2      A1
3      A1
3      A2
3      A3
3      A4

resutl:

ID   subject
1     A1
1     A2
1     NA
2     A1
2     NA
2     NA
3     A1
3     A2
3     A3
3     A4
```

So each `ID` has at least 3 records.
How can I do this in R? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `tidyr::complete`. We create a `record_number` column that counts the records for each `ID` group. Then `complete` will let us fill in all missing rows, so each group has as many records as the group that had the most (or if no groups have 3 records, they are filled up to 3 rows). Then we filter out the extraneous rows beyond 3 per group that were added.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- read_table2(
"ID    subject
1      A1
1      A2
2      A1
3      A1
3      A2
3      A3
3      A4" 
)

tbl %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(record_number = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(ID, record_number = 1:max(3, max(record_number))) %>%
  filter(record_number <=3 | !is.na(subject))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>       ID record_number subject
#>    <dbl>         <int> <chr>  
#>  1     1             1 A1     
#>  2     1             2 A2     
#>  3     1             3 <NA>   
#>  4     2             1 A1     
#>  5     2             2 <NA>   
#>  6     2             3 <NA>   
#>  7     3             1 A1     
#>  8     3             2 A2     
#>  9     3             3 A3     
#> 10     3             4 A4
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: It's not necessary, just habit when I don't plan to use those groups again. You are right that in this case it doesn't change what `complete` or `filter` do. Otherwise it can become a source of bugs if you assign the grouped table to something and forget it's grouped.

Answer (score 2):

One way would using only base R would be

```
#Get number of rows for each ID and subtract it from min_row_id
#keep only those which we need to add 
temp <- subset(aggregate(subject~ID, df, function(x) min_row_id - length(x)), 
               subject < min_row_id & subject > 0)

#Add those new rows and rbind the original dataframe
new_df <- rbind(df, do.call(rbind, mapply(function(x, y) 
                    data.frame(ID = x, subject = rep(NA, y)), 
                    temp$ID, temp$subject, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)))

#If needed order them according to ID
new_df[order(new_df$ID), ]

#   ID subject
#1   1      A1
#2   1      A2
#8   1    <NA>
#3   2      A1
#9   2    <NA>
#10  2    <NA>
#4   3      A1
#5   3      A2
#6   3      A3
#7   3      A4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `base` alternative. Use `tapply` to index (`[`) 'subject' within each 'ID', from 1 to `max` of group `length` and 3 (min_row_id). For indexes which exceed group length, the corresponding value is `NA`.

Recreate 'ID' of correct length by `rep`licating the name of the list elements to the length of each element (`lengths`). Use `unlist` to create a 'subject' column.

```
l <- tapply(d$subject, d$ID, function(x) x[1:(max(c(length(x), 3)))])
data.frame(id = rep(names(l), lengths(l)), subject = unlist(l, use.names = FALSE))
#    id subject
# 1   1      A1
# 2   1      A2
# 3   1    <NA>
# 4   2      A1
# 5   2    <NA>
# 6   2    <NA>
# 7   3      A1
# 8   3      A2
# 9   3      A3
# 10  3      A4
```